# Percentage properties in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

My application has many models, many of which contain percentage data. These are represented as `decimal` or `decimal?` structs in the model. However, not all properties with `decimal` structs are percentages. Some should be treated like regular decimals.

The percentages need special attention:

- For display, they should use `{0:P2}` format. (I have this part working.)
- For editing, they should allow the same format as the display, i.e. "95" or "95%" or "95.00 %" all bind to a value of 0.95.

I started down the road of creating a `PercentModelBinder` that implements `IModelBinder`, but then realized that you can only apply the `ModelBinderAttribute` to a *class*, not a property.

What's the best way to handle this case where *some* (but not all) uses of a type need special handling both for display and binding?

Every solution I think of smells badly of overkill, fighting the MVC framework. Surely there is a better way than:

- Creating a custom `Percentage` struct and using it as the basis for the IModelBinder and EditorTemplates, or
- Reimplementing the default binding behavior of `decimal` and `decimal?` and changing the parsing logic based on intimate knowledge of my model, or
- Implementing a custom model binder for each class that contains a percentage property, or
- Using fake proxy properties in the model (i.e. breaking MVC)

Comment: I think I'd consider writing a custom Data Annotation attribute if I were you. If that's something you're at all familiar with, take it and run with it. If not, comment back and I'll put some info together for you.

Comment: @Rick, I'd be very interested in seeing your implementation.

Comment: I'll get some links and sample code together tomorrow at the office and get them posted here.

Comment: I didn't get back to this until late today, and @Darin has already posted the gist of what I was going to outline, so I'll leave it in his hands. :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One possibility is to write a custom metadata aware attribute:

```
public class PercentageAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["percentage"] = metadata.EditFormatString;
    }
}
```

then decorate your view model properties that represent percentages with it:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:P2}")]
    [Percentage]
    public decimal? Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

and inside the custom model binder test for the presence of this value:

```
public class PercentageModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("percentage"))
        {
            var format = (string)bindingContext.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["percentage"];
            // TODO: do the custom parsing here
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        else
        {
            // Let the default parsing occur
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can register this model binder to all decimals.

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well, and was exactly the type of solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of representing your percentage properties using decimal primitives (see [Primitive Obsession](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/primitive-obsession)), why don't you create a Percentage type to wrap your desired functionality? You should have much more flexibility doing it that way...

Comment: Yes, that was the first potential solution I mentioned in the original question. I'm not opposed to it, but it seems rather draconian to have to create another entire domain class just to get around the formatting and binding behaviour of a framework.

Comment: Well, if you look at it from the perspective that it represents a concrete business requirement, it seems much more appropriate to me.

Answer (score 0):

Bind to a `string` in your view model. Then when do the conversion back to the real model.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that. (I added that as a solution I'd rather not consider in my question.) But then I have to do this with *every single percentage property*, plus it pretty much breaks the MVC paradigm.