# Using abstract view model in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have an input form containing several input fields. Each input field has a `ElementModel` which has properties basically for the label and the value. The input fields to display are specified in a XML document, so I have kind of a dynamic view with only a list of elements.

The problem is, that each element should be either displayed as a decimal or as percentage value. And of course, if it's a percentage value, the user shoud be able to input something like "45%" and the value in the model should then be 0.45.

My first thought when I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234966/percentage-properties-in-mvc-3) article was to use an abstract view model class with an abstract property for the value and to define a `PercentageElementModel` deriving from my base `ElementModel`class that makes use of a custom model binder. Unfortunately, if I use that abstract base class in my view, the data annotations made in the `PercentageElementModel`are ignored.

Do you have any idea of how I can solve this? I don't want to use strings in my view model and do the parsing by myself as this will break the MVC pattern. Are there some other ways to achieve my goal?

Here are some code snippets:

```
public abstract class ElementModel
{
    public string ElementName { get; set; }

    public ElementType ElementType { get; set; }

    public abstract double? ElementValue { get; set; }
}

public class PercentageElementModel : ElementModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:P2}")]
    public override double? ElementValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I recently detailed a solution for this issue in my answer to this question: [Model inheritance possible when using strongly-typed view in MVC3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311907/model-inheritance-possible-when-using-strongly-typed-view-in-mvc3/8320821#8320821)

Comment: @Andrew Barber,  I strongly disagree with your interpretation of the FAQ.  This is a link to an answer to a similar question.  It fundamentally answers the OP's question, so it should not be converted to a comment.  Please review the FAQ guidelines you cited.

Comment: @counsellorben Thanks for the link, that perfectly answers my question. Actually, I found another solution that also fits my needs. I will post it here as answer)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another solution as my problem is more a matter of display formatting than of validation: I wrote a custom ModelBinder which checks the input string of the text box. If it ends with a trailing '%' sign, I will devide the value by 100. Here's the code.

```
public class DoubleModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };

            double? actualValue = null;
            try
            {
                // cut trailing '%'
                if (valueResult.AttemptedValue.EndsWith("%"))
                {
                    var strValue = valueResult.AttemptedValue.Substring(0, valueResult.AttemptedValue.Length - 1);
                    actualValue = double.Parse(strValue, valueResult.Culture) / 100;
                }
                else
                {
                    actualValue = Convert.ToDouble(valueResult.AttemptedValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                modelState.Errors.Add(e);
            }

            bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
            return actualValue;
        }
    }
```

The rest happens in the view itself. To display the correct format, I use a simple `ToString()` method with a percentage format string assigned if needed. And if the user enters a numeric value without '%', a jQuery's `blur()` event will append the '%' sign to the user's input. Perfectly works for me although this is not the best answer for my own question.